# Doesn't the Yetzer Hora have a huge advantage over the Yetzer Tov?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Seeing as the Yetzer Tov loves Mitzvos, we can safely assume that he only uses a Kosher phone to aid him in the fight against the Yetzer Hora. But the Yetzer Hora himself has the latest smartphone with him with all of its bells and whistles.

I can imagine it now. By the time the Yetzer Tov searches through his old Nokia 3200 for Chizuk Hotline 225, the Yetzer Hora has put into Google Maps "Averois in New York" and been presented with 539 options.

How is the Yetzer Tov supposed to compete?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Sounds like the makings of a Shpy story.

Answer (score 5):

That's why the Talmud says (Kiddushin 30a)

> תנא דבי ר' ישמעאל בני אם פגע בך מנוול זה משכהו לבית המדרש
>
> If you encounter that disgusting one (the Yetzer Hara), drag him to the Beis Medrash.

where he will encounter this sign:

[image: Sign announcing prohibition to bring computers and smartphones into the Beis Medrash]

Having grown reliant on his phone and not being allowed to bring it into the Beis Medrash, he will be left weaponless.

In case he thinks he can sneak it in as a [Smart Watch Phone Rock](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00933MKYY), the Talmud continues:

> אם אבן הוא נימוח... שנאמר אבנים שחקו מים
>
> If it is a Rock, it will melt... as it is says "Rocks will be dissolved by water"

Being so close to his hands, the motherboard will get fried by the water at the washing station sinks.